# Can XAPO filters be applied globally?

Tags: windows, xaudio2

I was looking into Microsoft XAudio2 XAPO and I guess it is only for audio streams that are sent through XAudio2, or can it be applied as a system-wide audio filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.winvistatips.com/system-wide-audio-filter-driver-t819251.html) XAPO effects can't be applied globally